# Setting up RhodeCode on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: python, windows-server-2008-r2, rhodecode

I am trying to set up RhodeCode on WS2008R2, but keep on receiving the following error message at the "pip install rhodecode" stage:

"couldn't import standard bz2 (incomplete python install)"

this seems to happen at the stage when the installation process tries to install mercurial.

I am not quite sure where to go with this, as I have zero experience with python. I am following the guide provided from rhodecode: [guide](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/installation_win.html#installation-win)

Python version is 2.7.

Please help!

Comment: Also from what I understand from the guide is that I am setting up a virtualized environment for python (in the RhodeCode/Env folder). Is it trying to look for the "bz2" module there? Or in the global C:/Python27 directory?

Comment: Well, finally someone else is having the same issue (I thought I was the only one!). Hence the fav I suppose. Cannot find anything that would explain this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems as if rhodecode have updated their step-by-step installation process and have included sections for 64-bit OS systems. Have tried on windows server 2012 and it works!

[Link to guide](http://rhodecode.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_win.html)